# imagerotate not keeping transparency in background

Tags: php

This question might look like a duplicate but I haven't found an answer yet so am posting it again. I am working on image rotation and am using php. On rotating image using imagerotate() the image leaves a background either black or it can be made into white according to some solutions on official php website. I have gone through almost all the posts on the internet but didn't find a single answer that resolved the issue. My question is that whether is it possible to completely make the background transparent? I have added the code now. This code does the rotation work on the image.

```
    $imagew = imagecreatefrompng('test.png');  //I have changed the path to simple example
    imagerotate($imagew, $angle, 0);

    imagealphablending($imagew, false);
    imagesavealpha($imagew, true);

    imagepng($imagew);
    imagedestroy($imagew);
```

[image: sample image 1][image: sample image 2 after rotation]

Comment: Let's see the code in question. We'll possibly be able to better help and point out issues.

Comment: Hi @Adam I have written the code